# Expectation of a composite Markov-Gamma distribution

Tags: symbolic, probability-or-statistics, markov-chains

In a model I have a discrete two-state first order Markov process, defined by a (2x2) transition matrix with two free parameters. If the first state occurs then the process outputs zero for that period. If the second state occurs then the process outputs a Gamma-distributed random variable characterised by another two parameters.

I can work out the theoretical mean and variance of the overall stationary process using pen and paper, but I am unsure how to check my results (and also I want to practice my Mathematica) using symbolic calculations. Put another way, I would like to know how to calculate the mean and variance to which the composite Markov-Gamma process will converge. My code is below - all I have currently is a way to calculate the mean of the Markov process, P, and its stationary mean (Mean[S]). However, I would like to be able to derive the mean and variance of R inserted into P for times when the process is in state 2, and zeros for when P is in state 1. Many thanks! Ben

```
M = {{1 - pdw, pdw}, {pwd, 1 - pwd}}
P  = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0}, M]
S = StationaryDistribution[P]
R = GammaDistribution[a,b]
```

Comment: things like `PDF[P[n], k] // PiecewiseExpand` or `Mean[P[n]] // FullSimplify`?

Comment: I did not understand the link with R?

Comment: R is a gamma distribution which determines the outcome of the series if it is in state '2'. Otherwise the process outputs zero in state '1'.

Answer (score 4):

With

```
$Assumptions = {0 <= pdw <= 1, 0 <= pwd <= 1};
trM = {{1 - pdw, pdw}, {pwd, 1 - pwd}};
dmP = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0}, trM];
gD = GammaDistribution[a, b];
```

the mean and variance of the described process for a time slice at time t are

```
mean = Expectation[(m[t] - 1)*g, {m \[Distributed] dmP, g \[Distributed] gD}] 
variance = Expectation[((m[t] - 1)*g - mean)^2, {m \[Distributed] dmP, g \[Distributed] gD}] // Simplify
```

> ```
> -((a b pdw (-1 + (1 - pdw - pwd)^t))/(pdw + pwd))
> -((a b^2 pdw (-1 + (1 - pdw - pwd)^t) (pdw + a pdw (1 - pdw - pwd)^t + pwd + a pwd))/(pdw + pwd)^2)
> ```

The stationary mean and variance are

```
stationaryMean = Limit[mean, t -> ∞]
stationaryVariance = Limit[variance, t -> ∞]
```

> ```
> (a b pdw)/(pdw + pwd)
> (a b^2 pdw (pdw + pwd + a pwd))/(pdw + pwd)^2
> ```

---

An alternative approach is to define a `TransformedDistribution`

```
trD = TransformedDistribution[(m - 1)* g, {m \[Distributed] SliceDistribution[dmP, t], 
       g \[Distributed] gD}]
```

and then calculate the stationary mean and variance with

```
Mean@trD ~Limit~ (t -> ∞)
Variance@trD ~Limit~ (t -> ∞)
```

---

---

Performing simulations:
One can use the `TransformedDistribution` to perform simulations:

```
rvSim = RandomVariate[trD /. {pdw -> 0.2, pwd -> 0.7, a -> 1, b -> 2, t -> #}] & /@ Range[1000];
```

Nevertheless, the calculation time is much lower, if one first uses `RandomFunction` with the `DiscreteMarkovProcess` and than does the state dependent transformation:

```
rf = RandomFunction[dmP /. {pdw -> 0.2, pwd -> 0.7}, {1, 10000}];

f[x_Integer] := 0 /; x == 1
f[x_Integer] := RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[1, 2]] /; x == 2

sim = f /@ (rf["Path"][[All, 2]]);
```

Comment: I am impressed you seem to have understood what the OP wanted based on limited evidence :-)

Comment: Thanks to Karsten for answering my question - that helps me understand how to approach this problem.

Comment: @Karsten. Can I ask how I can simulate draws from the transformed distribution? I have tried RandomFunction (substituting in the required parameters with numbers), but this does not seem to work.

Comment: @user2003951 your difficulties seem to be due to the circumstance that for *Mathematica* there is a bigger difference between distributions and random processes than for you. `RandomFunction` is for processes, not for distributions. For distributions you should use `RandomVariate`. I'll make an edit to my answer, in order to give you an example.

Comment: @Karsten - that's great thank you. Yes, the latter option is much faster. Can I ask though, how do I actually plot the data from the simulation? I have tried ListPlot[sim] but that doesn't seem to work. Sorry!

Comment: @user2003951 `ListPlot[sim, PlotRange -> All]` works for me. Does, e.g. `sim[[;; 20]]`, give you a `List` of values?

Answer (score 0):

Following closely the documentation for [`DiscreteMarkovProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html) 
(I am no  expert though…)

M = {{1 - w, w}, {d, 1 - d}}
    P = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0}, M]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Mean[P[n]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Variance[P[n]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graph[P]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = RandomFunction[P /. w -> 1/2 /. d -> 1/4, {0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis, Ticks -> {Automatic, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MarkovProcessProperties[P /. w -> 1/2 /. d -> 1/4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now for the stationary process

```
S = StationaryDistribution[P] // FullSimplify;

PDF[S, n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Mean[S] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Variance[S] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, although it is not quite what I am looking for. I can derive the properties of a simple Markov chain using Mathematica. What I can't do is form the composite process consisting of zeros if the process is in state 1, and a gamma distributed random variable in state 2. I don't know how to make this composite process using Mathematica, then symbollically derive its long run mean and variance. Thanks!

Comment: ok I cannot help you there because I know too little about Markov processes. There are ways to compose probabilities in mathematica: may be someone else will help.